# Self Sizing Cells With Asynchronous ImageLoading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, lazy-loading

**Update:** This [Github](https://github.com/akshaypakanati/SelfSizingCellTest) link contains the project. If possible download and tap on Reload on top you'll get to know the difference. and Mr. [Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860967/zhang) thank you for "Aspect Scale to Fill" suggestion. it helped me little.

I've a tableview which loads images Asynchronously (with AFNetworking UIImageView Category Class).Images are compressing for first time on visible cells. Once I reload again or scroll op and down Images are adjusting according to its size.

**Basically I'll get different size Images. Which width should be cell width, height can be anything**

Implemented all necessary steps for selfsizing(proper autolayout constraints and proper delegate methods)

```
//my tableview setup     
self.tblTest?.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0 //i've tried with all possible guesses and 
//tried with delegate also 
self.tblTest?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I've added constraints as below:

[image]

in my test cell.

```
func setUpImage(url:NSURL){
  //tried with another function also without NSURLRequest
    self.imvTest?.setImageWithURLRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url),
                                        placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "store_placeholder"),
                                        success: { (requset, response, image) -> Void in
        self.imvTest?.image = image
        print(image.size)

        }, failure: { (error) -> Void in

            self.imvTest?.image = nil
    })
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

**How can i prevent image squeezing for the first time??**

**P.S: I don't think its correct to reload table view each and time image is being set.**

Please suggest me what i've been missing and any content priorities etc.,??

Comment: You tried setting the content mode to Aspect Scale to Fill on your imageView ?

Comment: Yes @Zhang I've tried . I'll post the project on git hub soon

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

after setting the image in the success closure

Or try `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` with the indexPath of the cell after setting the image

Comment: Did you implement the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: First of all, did it work? Reloading only the cell at indexPath?; the issue with the performance, can you elaborate please?

Comment: we just can't call reload in each and every cell.. just to reset row height..
it's a bad idea for this situation.

Comment: This helped me with loading UIWebView in a UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening is that the cell gets laid out with its original content size. Then the new image asynchronously comes in and gets set. Typically you set the data for the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which occurs before cell layout. However when an image comes in asynchronously, layout has already happened, so it's too late.

When a new image comes in, ***the data has changed***, so you need to tell the tableview to reload the data.

Instead of reloading the tableview as a whole however, you can [reload an individual cell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) when the image comes in. This will of course be much more performant than reloading the entire tableview.

Comment: With this method whenever cell content is being set i should reload entire cell need to reload explicitly.. So I should reload parallely along with tablview right!?